# The file “launchPackager.command” could not be executed because you do not have appropriate access privileges

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, macos-catalina, react-native-firebase

Hello I am trying to Add Firebase to my react-native project.
At the end when i try to launch my IOS project:
The file “launchPackager.command” could not be executed because you do not have appropriate access privileges.To view or change access privileges, select the file in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.
[image]

I have already changed my privacy and settings on my Mac(os catalina 10.15.4):

sudo spctl --master-disable
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue.
In my case, it was resolved by giving executable permission to the file.

```sh
chmod u+x /path/to/file.command
```